# Redirection and Wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a form that will be completed in two parts. First, you indicate the user information, then you choose between prestataire and employeur, and are redirected accordingly. Before being redirected to the prestataire or employeur form, the user data shall be saved. I've created the model, view and controller for the user, that I'll add downward, but i'm presently having an error : wrong number of arguments (0 for 1); and I'm stuck. Thanks in advance for your help.

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :prestataire
  has_one :employeur
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, :forename, :surname, :phone, :civility, presence: true
  validates :password, confirmation: true
  has_secure_password
end
```

View:

```
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :civility, 'Titre de civilité: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :civility %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :forename, 'Prénom: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :forename %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :surname, 'Nom de famille: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :surname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email, 'Email: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password, 'Mot de passe: ' %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password, size: 40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirmation de mot de passe: ' %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, size: 40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone, 'Numéro de téléphone: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Employeur', name: 'employeur' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Prestataire', name: 'prestataire' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @users = User.all
      end

      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
      end

      def new
        @user = User.new
      end

      # GET /users/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /users
      # POST /users.json
      def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @user.save
            #if params[:commit] == 'Employeur'
            format.html { redirect_to @employeur, notice: "Renseignez vos informations d'employeur" }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
            #else 
            #format.html { redirect_to @prestataire, notice: "Renseignez vos informations de prestataire" }
            #format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
            #end
          else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /users/1
      # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @user.update(user_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'edit' }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /users/1
      # DELETE /users/1.json
      def destroy
        @user.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to users_url }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

    private
      def user_params
            params.require[:user].permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :surname, :forename, :civility, :phone, :Employeur)
      end

    end
```

I had the routes just in case:

```
Workplace::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :prestataires
  resources :employeurs
  resources :projets
  resources :feedbacks
  resources :offres
  root 'projets#index'
```

The error is identified to be on this line, in the controller part:

```
params.require[:user].permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :surname, :forename, :civility, :phone, :Employeur)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in that line; you're using square brackets instead of parentheses, so it should be like this `params.require(:user)`. Don't forget the typo @NickM mentioned.

Comment: Someone down-voted my answer, so I deleted it. For the record, the typo in my answer was in your params.require line at the end. You capitalized a symbol. Good catch Ahmad.